# Python - drawing randomly n numbers integer from range

Tags: python

I would like get the same effect as when I use `getn`, but it should be integers numer from interval `[1...100]`

Comment: What have done to find a solution?

Comment: `getn` is not a python function I am aware of

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you're asking. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import randint

randint(1, 100)    # => 86
```

If you want a bunch of numbers,

```
def getn_rand(n):
    return [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)]
```

or if the numbers have to be distinct (no duplicates),

```
from random import sample

def getn_rand_distinct(n):
    return sample(range(1, 101), n)
```

Comment: I tried longly do it. It's crucial for me to this ditribution was normal

Comment: But your way don't draw n numbers, - only one

Comment: @xaweyNEW,  do you mean a random contiguous range or n totally random numbers?